# How Do I Handle Getting Injured Or Ill While Moving Out Of State (in USA)

Tags: usa, health, moving

I am planning to move out of state. I am in USA.

Looking at some places and sending in my resume.

I try to take best care of my health (my Primary Care Physician says I am healthier than her!), i.e stay at ideal weight, do 30 minutes exercise each day, don't watch TV, spend lot of time on housework.

My knee got sore on Friday, now it is paining that I have to call into work Sick tomorrow (hoping my PCP can see me just to make sure everything is ok).

I believe I got knee pain because I carry heavy lunch bag to work (I don't trust outside food unless it is coffee or tea), and I distributed the weight poorly, hence my left knee is in pain.

But here is my question. How do I handle situation if I get knee pain, or I get ill, etc while I am moving. The burden in 100% on my shoulders, no one is able to take care of me.

Please tell me what things I should consider. What life skills should I know. I'd like to make a plan so I can manage the unexpected.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Do you mean going to an Emergency Room? An Urgent Care clinic? Having up to date medical insurance? Calling for an ambulance? I'd also suggest that this isn't a good question for Travel.  But I have no idea what would be a better forum.  Expatriates? Life hacks? Health and fitness?

Comment: This was an open-ended question because I don't know how to handle sudden illness (that is unplanned). It was more towards handling things, such as preparing food even though you are injured, ill. I wish I knew of a better forum too!

Comment: The issue here, Marium, is that this is a question-answer forum, not a discussion board. Wide-ranging questions that stimulate discussion are not what we're after; what the forum seeks is questions that have declarative answers. You'll need to significantly narrow your scope here, or the question is likely to be closed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about travel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have health insurance with your current job, you can usually use [COBRA](https://www.dol.gov/general/topic/health-plans/cobra#:%7E:text=The%20Consolidated%20Omnibus%20Budget%20Reconciliation,voluntary%20or%20involuntary%20job%20loss%2C) to keep the coverage, even after you quit, until you're covered under a new policy.

COBRA, Consolidated Omnibus Budget Reconciliation Act, provides a way to continue your previous health insurance until you can enroll in a new plan. You do have to pay the premiums which may be quite expensive.

Comment: This is very helpful. I thought it was for dependents (on their parent's medical insurance) who graduated college and are looking for job.